# Difference between AICc delta<2 and AICc delta<4 in model.average

Tags: r, aic, phylogeny, mumin

I am running a PGLS (Phylogenetic Generalized Least Squares) model selection using the library 'MuMIn' and its functions, see below the code:

```r
    *# Perform PGLS function
    modelo <- pgls(ExtinctionRisk ~ PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + Island_Endemic  + Volancy + Habitat + New_Migration + Foraging , data = cdat, lambda = 'ML')
    dd1 <- dredge(modelo)
    subset(dd1, delta < 4)
    # Model average models with delta AICc < 4

    model.avg(dd1, subset = delta < 4)
    #or as a 95% confidence set:
    model.avg(dd1, subset = cumsum(weight) <= .95) # get averaged coefficients

    #'Best' model
    x<-summary(get.models(dd1, 1)[[1]])*
```

I am not sure what's the difference between using a delta AICc<4 than the thumb rule (delta<2)?

Comment: I cannot assess your question without a reproducible example or at least with a glimpse of the data https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example